# Is there any way I can handle exits in python?

Tags: python, exception, exit

I'm trying to build an automatic system in Tensorflow to help build models (essentially AutoML but with reinforcement learning in mind). Python keeps quitting unexpectedly due to the networks being sometimes massive. I'd like a way to handle the unexpected quits, like an error. Is there any way I can do this?

I've tried using the `atexit` builtin module, but it didn't work. My theory is that it has to be something from tensorflow's backend that's stopping this program.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with Tensorflow, but would a try: except: block help?

Comment: @ShaneSmiskol, do you mean catching all errors? I'll give that a go...

Comment: Yes, or just catching the specific error you're getting when it exits unexpectantly.

Comment: @ShaneSmiskol, didn't work. Thanks anyway. It doesn't give me any sort of error or anything, just kind of cuts back to the command/terminal line...